# What is the problem inside this Three.js skybox code?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to create a SkyBox with ThreeJS code. It didn't work. It just flash a second and turned to black. The code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        camera.position.z=5;

        var geometry=new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000,10000,10000);
        var cubeMaterials=camera
        [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/skydome.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/skydome.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/skydome.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/grass-texture.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/skydome.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.TextureLoader().load("img/skydome.jpg"), side:THREE.DoubleSide})
        ];

        //var cubeMaterial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(cubeMaterials);
        var cube=new THREE.Mesh(geometry,cubeMaterials);
        scene.add(cube);

        renderer.render(scene,camera);


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what's wrong inside. So what is the problem inside this code?

Comment: what does this do: `src="js/three.js"` What is the expected result? Please make it easier for folks who are wiling to help to learn your desired result and your progress in achieving the result.

Comment: src="js/three.js" references the three.js script. The expected result is to show a cube skybox with all texture loaded

Answer (score 1):

```
    var cubeMaterials=camera
    [
```

is wrong.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/CubeTextureLoader

Comment: So what is the possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that you perform the rendering only after all textures are loaded. I've updated you code by using `LoadingManager` to show you one possible solution.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry=new THREE.CubeGeometry(10000,10000,10000);

const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

const tex1 = loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif' );
const tex2 = loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg' );

manager.onLoad = function() {

 const cubeMaterials= [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex1, side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex1, side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex1, side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex2, side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex2, side:THREE.DoubleSide}),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:tex2, side:THREE.DoubleSide})
 ];

 const cube=new THREE.Mesh(geometry,cubeMaterials);
 scene.add(cube);

 renderer.render(scene,camera);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.117.1/build/three.js"></script>
```